# casperjs - fill form / post form - solving death by captcha

Tags: javascript, post, casperjs

have that simple Webform which i want to fill and than get text from the result page.

```
<html><head></head><body><table><tr><td>
<form method="post" action="http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="function"     value="picture2">
    <input type="text"   name="username"     value="">
    <input type="text"   name="password"     value="">
    <input type="file"   name="pict">
    <input type="text"   name="pict_to"      value="0">
    <input type="text"   name="pict_type"    value="0">
    <input type="text"   name="print_format" value="html">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
        </td></tr></table></body></html>
```

And just want to Post 3 Values to the Form. I tried with the following examples:

```
casper.start('http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html', function() {
    this.fillSelectors('#html>body>table>tbody>tr>td>form', {
        'input[name="username"]':    'loginname',
        'input[name="password"]':    'password',
        'input[name="pict"]':   'folder/file.jpeg'
    }, true);
});
```

or:

```
casper.open('http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html', {
    method: 'post',
    data:   {
        'username': 'loginname',
        'password':  'passwortd',
        'pict':  'folder/file.jpeg'
    },
     headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

and

```
casper.start('http://api.dbcapi.me/api/captcha', function() {
    this.fill('form', {
        'username':    'loginname',
        'password':    'passwort',
        'captchafile':   'folder/file.jpeg',
    }, true);
});
```

none of them work correct :-(

Comment: Well, the first snippet is wrong, because `<html>` has no `id="html"`, so remove the `#`. Also, you might want to lose `>tbody>` and replace it with a space. The second snippet is incomplete, because you don't show how you wait for the result. The third snippet contains another typo, because there is no `captchafile` form field.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! First Snippet in running well. Within the second Snippet i'm not sure what you mean with waiting for result.

Comment: Forget what I said about the second snippet. It's unlikely that it is used wrong. The form submit URL is wrong. Check what the action of the form contains.

Comment: Did this work for you @swapfile ?

Comment: Jep, that worked for me.